# Automatically send an email to list when blog is updated

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, email

I am trying to implement a system where a user makes a blog post (to a set category) and as part of that sequence, or in addition to, it does the following:

1. Create a new email based on a template
2. Populate the email with a snippet, or the excerpt text
3. Send to a predefined list

To labour the point; it isn't to email everyone, just the people in the aforementioned list.

Does anybody know of a plugin or email system to do this?

We currently use aweber but I cannot find the functionality to dynamically insert content from the post. It seems to only be able to do send a "Blog Updated, go here to enjoy it's awesomeness" type deal.

EDIT: Had a look at Subscribe2 [as detailed here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33255/subscribe2-configuration) to no avail.

Comment: Try the plugin Email posts to subscribers http://wordpress.org/plugins/email-posts-to-subscribers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list of possible plugins here http://wppluginmarket.com/22984/email-mailing-list-plugins/.

I responded to your other post too.

You don't say whether your 'list' is something you control, or whether users can subscribe to it.

I don't know mailpress well, in S2 one can manually add subscribers to the list (and not show the s2 subscribe widget for example)

Comment: We currently have a list in Campaign Monitor that we will import when needed.

We intend on having a few checkboxes in the members area where they can choose to either subscribe or not subscribe to the email, ideally this will be included but I am almost certain I will need to code that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MailChimp's RSS-to-email feature described [here](http://mailchimp.com/features/rss-to-email/), they also have a free plan for up to 2000 subscribers and 12k emails per month.

I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for, but [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.google.com) allows people to subscribe to your blog and receive emails each time you update your RSS, for free.