# Subscribe2 Configuration

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I am trying to configure Subscribe2 to have the user select which categories they want rather than the "all or nothing" approach it seems to have.

Essentially I am using WP as a CMS as opposed to a blog roll, but I currently have 2 "blogrolls" represented by displaying the most recent post on the page (they are page length posts). I would like to send an email when Cat 1 OR Cat 2 is updated, likewise with future categories, but have the user be able to select only Cat 1 emails.

I have read the FAQ to no avail, is this actually supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is joshau

Thee S2 admin interface could be better, but it is stable, has been around a long time.

You can exclude categories (eg all except your 2) and can allow users to select which categories they want from within that.

I'm not the author, but I have it in use in a few sites and am nearly done writing an 'add-on' that sits on top and tweaks a few things the way I want them..... (html, unsubscribe, cron job visibility etc)

Comment: how would I do that, I couldn't find that option.

Comment: Hi Joshua - go to your subscribe 2 settings and scroll down, down, down, past the "email templates".  The next heading is "excluded categories".